# Convergence in probability of $\max \bigg\{ \frac{|\sum_{i=k+1}^n e_{i}|}{n-k}; 1\leq k\leq n(1-a_{n})\bigg\}$

Tags: probability, statistics

Please, help me with this application of Hajek-Renyi inequality...

Let $e_{i}, \: i=1,\dots,n$ be iid random variables with zero expectation and $var(e_{i})=\sigma^2$, $\lbrace a_{i}\rbrace$ is a sequence of numbers such that $0<a_{i}<1$.
We want to show that

$$\max{ \bigg\{ \frac{|\sum_{i=k+1}^n e_{i}|}{n-k}; 1\leq k\leq n(1-a_{n})\bigg\} } = O_{p}(\sqrt{(n a_{n})^{-1}})$$.

It should be an application of Hajek-Renyi inequality which states that if $\lbrace U_{n} = \sum_{j=1}^n u_{j}, \: F_{n},\: n\geq 1 \rbrace$ is an $L_{2}$ martingale and $\lbrace b_{n},\: n\geq 1 \rbrace$ is a positive, nondecreasing real sequence, then for any $\lambda>0$ holds that

$$ P\bigg(\max \bigg\{ \bigg|\frac{U_{j}}{b_{j}}\bigg|; 1\leq j\leq n \bigg\} >\lambda \bigg) \le \lambda^{-2}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{E(u_j^2)}{b_{j}^2}$$.